# Python pyopenssl signed certificate error (Firefox: SEC_ERROR_REUSED_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL, chrome: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

I'm creating an antivirus for a project at the Institute. As part of the project, I am trying to create a proxy server that can intercept https data.
To do this, I created a CA certificate and attached it to the Firefox and Windows storage. It was created using:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto    
import os
    
KEY_FILE = "self_sertificate.key"
CERT_FILE = "self_sertificate.crt"
    
def get_self_sert():
    k = crypto.PKey()
    k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
        
    cert = crypto.X509()
    cert.set_version(2)
    cert.get_subject().C = "US"
    cert.get_subject().ST = "State"
    cert.get_subject().L = "City"
    cert.get_subject().O = "Organization"
    cert.get_subject().OU = "Organization CA"
    cert.get_subject().CN = "Organization CA"
    cert.set_serial_number(24695562)
    
    cert.add_extensions([
        crypto.X509Extension(b"basicConstraints", True, b"CA:TRUE, pathlen:0"),
        crypto.X509Extension(b"subjectKeyIdentifier", False, b"hash", subject=cert),
    ])
        
    cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
    cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(k)
    cert.sign(k, 'sha256')
    return cert,k
   
def create_self_signed_cert(dir='\\cert'):      
    cert,k = get_self_sert()
    
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + dir, CERT_FILE), "wb") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
    
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + dir, KEY_FILE), "wb") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k))
```

The creation of the subsequent certificates:

```
 def create_cert_req(url):
        pKey = crypto.PKey()
        pKey.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
    
        req = crypto.X509Req()
        subj = req.get_subject()
        
        subj.C = 'US'
        subj.ST = 'State'
        subj.L = 'City'
        subj.O = 'Organization'
        subj.OU = 'Organization CA'
        subj.CN = url
        subj.emailAddress = 'example@example.org'
        
        req.set_pubkey(pKey)
        req.sign(pKey,'sha256')
        return req

def create_signed_cert_demo(url,serial=106570068,dir='\\lib\\cert\\',cert_name=str(random.randint(100000,1000000))):
    req = create_cert_req(url)
    ca_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open(os.getcwd() + dir + CERT_FILE).read())
    ca_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open(os.getcwd() + dir + KEY_FILE).read())

    cert = crypto.X509()
    
    cert.set_version(2)
    cert.set_serial_number(serial)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
    cert.set_issuer(ca_cert.get_subject())
    cert.set_subject(req.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(req.get_pubkey())
    cert.add_extensions([crypto.X509Extension(b"subjectAltName", False, b"DNS:" + url.encode())])
    
    cert.sign(ca_key,'sha256')
    
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + dir, cert_name+'.crt'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
        
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + dir, cert_name+'.key'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,cert.get_pubkey()))
    return cert_name+'.crt',cert_name+'.key'
```

Then a proxy was created that accepts https connections and creates new certificates:

```
cert_crt,cert_key = certificate.create_signed_cert_demo(headers['host']) # Calling the function that creates the certificate
print('\\lib\\cert\\'+cert_crt)
print('\\lib\\cert\\'+cert_key)
conn = ssl.wrap_socket(conn,server_side=True,certfile=os.getcwd() +'\\lib\\cert\\'+cert_crt,keyfile=os.getcwd() +'\\lib\\cert\\'+cert_key)
data = conn.recv(1024)
```

when I go to http sites through the browser, my proxy works fine, but when I go to an https site, an error appears:

```
Firefox:
SEC_ERROR_REUSED_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL

Chrome:
ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Error in Python:

```
File "Proxy.py", line 102, in <module>
    conn.start()
  File "Proxy.py", line 52, in start
    conn = ssl.wrap_socket(conn,server_side=True,certfile=os.getcwd() +'\\lib\\cert\\'+cert_crt,keyfile=os.getcwd() +'\\lib\\cert\\'+cert_key)
  File "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1405, in wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Examples of certificates:
CA

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

example.org

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: The browser is telling you that the certificate that you created doesn't represent the site in question, which is something the browser is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that browsers remember certificates within a single session. To solve the problem, you need to save the certificates and use them.
Updated the function create_signed_cert_demo:

```
def create_signed_cert_demo(url,serial=random.randint(1,100000000),dir='\\lib\\cert\\',cert_name=str(random.randint(100000,1000000))):
    dir_list = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + dir)
    if url + '.crt' in dir_list:
        return url + '.crt', url + '.key'
    req = create_cert_req(url)
    ca_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open(os.getcwd() + dir + CERT_FILE).read())
    ca_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open(os.getcwd() + dir + KEY_FILE).read())
    
    cert = crypto.X509()
        
    cert.set_version(2)
    cert.set_serial_number(serial)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
    cert.set_issuer(ca_cert.get_subject())
    cert.set_subject(req.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(req.get_pubkey())
    cert.add_extensions([crypto.X509Extension(b"subjectAltName", False, b"DNS:" + url.encode())])
        
    cert.sign(ca_key,'sha256')
    
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + dir, url+'.crt'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
        
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + dir, url+'.key'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,cert.get_pubkey()))
    return url+'.crt',url+'.key'
```

Answer (score 0):

> SEC_ERROR_REUSED_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL

You are using the same serial number (hard coded to 106570068) for different certificates issued by the same CA. But each certificate issued by a CA must have a different serial number.

> ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

The CA is probably not properly imported as a trusted CA into the browser. But it might also simply be a slightly wrong and less specific error message triggered by essentially the same problem shown by Firefox.

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

This is just the side effect of the browser rejecting the certificate.